# Set fixed height for fixed position div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

My site have two div vertically and both heights are vary. Therefor I tried to set top value for below div by using JQuery when it become a fixed position.

JQuery code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".suggest").css("top",$(".contents").outerHeight(true));
});
```

"contents" is above div class name and "suggest" is below div class name. Height is not defined in css code. My problem is above div height will change when it become fixed. Then according to above div height, top value become a smaller and below div overlap with above div.How to solve it out. I want to set top value of below div, height of above div before fixed.

Comment: Why not put them both in a container and have that one position: fixed; instead? Also: jQuery*

Comment: Can you make jsfiddle or plnkr? Do you really need to use fixed positions?

Comment: @JonasGrumann because div will change when web page is resize.

Comment: @Martin yeah i want fixed position.

Comment: "because div will change when web page is resize" can you elaborate that? Tell me more, I think there should be another way

Comment: @JonasGrumann look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38459262/three-columns-div-layout-design-with-adjustable this is my div style. I want to fix blue and pink divs in first image of three images.